# Expected value of the sum of $n$ dice rolls.

Tags: probability, expected-value

We roll a dice exactly $n$ times. What is the expected value of the sum of the outocomes?

I have given this problem some thought, but I don't know how to tackle this. The problem is, that each sum has a different probability of coming out. For example, there is only one way to achieve the sum $6n$, $5n$ etc, but more than one way to achieve $4n + 4$.

Is there a clever way to tackle this?

Comment: Have you ever heard of "linearity of expectation?"  The average result on each die is $3.5$.  The average sum $n$ dice is quite simply then $3.5\times n$.

Comment: What is the expected value for $n=1$? What for $n=2$?

Answer (score 3):

Because of the linearity of expectations, the expectation of $n$ dice rolls is simply $n\times E(X)$ where $E(X)$ is the expectation of a single die.

Comment: I can't believe that this answer is so simple..
I thought about this solution, but have never heard of the "linearity of expectation"
and the fact that some sums are more likely than others advised me against this.